# How to test native Android method in Flutter App with FlutterDriver?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-test

My Flutter app uses the native Android library.
That is, it uses the `MethodChannel`.

Now, I want to test the result of calling the native library's processing via the `MethodChannel`.
Since the `MethodChannel` requires calling Java processes, the test should be an Integration Test, not a Unit Test.

How can I run any method in Integration Test on my app?

Here is my test code.

```dart
// app.dart
void main() {
  enableFlutterDriverExtension();
  app.main();
}
```

```dart
// app_test.dart
void main() {

  FlutterDriver driver;
  group("MyTests", () {
    setUpAll(() async {
      driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
    });

    tearDownAll(() async {
      if (driver != null) {
        driver.close();
      }
    });

    test("Test1", () async {
      var result1 = await CallNativeMethodWithMethodChannel.method1(value: -1);
      expect(false, result1);
      var result2 = await CallNativeMethodWithMethodChannel.method1(value: 0);
      expect(false, result2);
      var result3 = await CallNativeMethodWithMethodChannel.method1(value: 1);
      expect(true, result3);
    });

  });
}
```

When this test code is executed, result1, result2, and result3 will always be null. This means that the method is not executed on the app.

How can I execute method1 on my app?

(Of course, I know that it is possible to test if I prepare a button on the app screen to run the test and tap it from the test code, but in reality, we have more than 100 items to test and it is not practical to prepare more than 100 buttons.)

**Note** :
**I need to test the result of a native method call for a reason.
In other words, it is not appropriate to mock the execution result of a native method.
Also, I want to test a combination of Dart code and native methods, so I am not testing "only" the native methods.**